# Httpd Configuration -- Accessing a folder

Tags: linux, apache

So I have the following situation. My root folder is /var/www/html. If I have a file in there called test and I do a

```
wget ip-address/test
```

everything is good. But if I add a folder called bla in html and I do the following

```
wget ip-address/bla/test
```

I get a 500 error. If I just do a

```
wget ip-address/bla
```

I get a 403 permission denied. I tried going into httpd.conf file and added the directory as follows:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/bla">
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And that didn't change anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Fri Jun 15 15:10:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.2.32] (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/html/kickstart/kk' failed
[Fri Jun 15 15:10:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.2.32] Premature end of script headers: kk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a directory listing, you need:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/bla">
Options Indexes
...
</Directory>
```

The directory listing will only work if the "DirectoryIndex" directive is not defined.

Comment: Note: You may need to restart apache to see the changes you made in httpd.conf

Comment: Okay I did as you said. I disabled the Directory Index as well and I restarted Apache, but to to avail.

Comment: When you say "but to to avail", what did you do exactly? Can you show what your <Directory> configurations are now?

Comment: <Directory /var/www/html/kickstart/>
   Options Indexes
   AllowOverride None
   order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
Also I Disabled the directory index and restarted apache. It didn't work. ps. sorry for the typo.

Comment: When you say "It didn't work", what are you trying to do exactly (what command did you run?)? And is there any error message you are getting specifically?

Comment: I'm performing a wget ipaddress/kickstart/kk I get the following error message [root@cn-r2-32 ~]# wget http://IP/kickstart/kk
--2012-06-15 16:01:19--  http://IP/kickstart/kk
Connecting to IP:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2012-06-15 16:01:19 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

Comment: what is "kk" is it a directory? Are you trying to list the contents of that directory? Your problem is quite confusing because your original question is different from the one you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder 'bla' you added has read permissions for process owner of httpd? Use chmod/chown to create access permissions and try again.